# PHP mail() - marked as spam

Tags: php, email, spam

My emails that are send by mail() are getting directly into the spam box, tested with GMAIL and HOTMAIL.
So:

- I have dedicated server
- My server ip is not listed on any blacklists

This is my code:

```
function send_email($recipient, $sender, $subject, $email_body){
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$sender;
mail($recipient,$subject,$email_body,$headers);
}

$from = 'info@domain.com';
$subject    = 'subject';
$email_body = '<h1 style="text-align:center;">Title</h1><p>Message</p>';
send_email($userbday['email'], $from, $subject, $email_body);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could it be your server is on a blacklist?

Comment: i checked and i'm not blacklisted anywhere

Comment: You can have some informations on this site: http://www.mail-tester.com

Comment: Use 5th parameter for mail function to set the return path http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Can you give me an example how to add the 5th parameter?

Comment: When you say you have a dedicated server, do you mean that you have a dedicated server from a hosting provider, or do you mean that you're running your email server personally (e.g. from your home)?

Comment: I have a dedicated server from HostDime

Answer (score 1):

Try to setup an SPF record for your domain.

Also

**Email is serious business.**

Try transactional email service providers

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your email looks exactly as spam. It sometimes happens...
All my applications sends email - depending on how the client prepare the email templates - some are treated as spam almost instantly, some not.

Setting SPF Record can help, but also check (and use) some blacklist emails for your own good - like people who dont want to receive your emila should never be bothered again as they can trigger your server to be in the black lists (for example spamcop).

Comment: How can I setup SPF Record?

Comment: This is what i found by happy google searching (and it is quite simple)  https://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/

Also if you want some information about the SPF itself here is nice wiki article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework